# ¿Por qué mi element.textContent NO evalúa bien?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo 3 equitetas, un label con su valor ya predefinido, un input text con valor vacío y un checkbox inhabilitado. Quiero que cuando el label tenga el valor "ASISTIO" la etiqueta input text también tenga ese valor y el checkbox este habilitado. Y cuando el label tenga el valor "FALTO" la etiqueta input text tenga esa mismo valor y el checkbox este inhabilitado.

Para lograrlo utilizo este siguiente script:

```
$(".lbl-asistencia").each(function (index, element) {
        if (element.textContent == "ASISTIO") {
            $(".chk-asistencia").prop("checked", true)
            $(".txt-asistencia").val("ASISTIO");
        }
        else {
            $(".chk-asistencia").prop("checked", false)
            $(".txt-asistencia").val("FALTO");
        }
    });
```

Pero el resultado que me regresa es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo me pone ASISTIO, cuando en  realidad solo hay un valor ASISTIO y los otros son FALTO.

Cómo podría arreglar esto?

**Mi código**

```js
$(".lbl-asistencia").each(function (index, element) {
            if (element.textContent == "ASISTIO") {
                $(".chk-asistencia").prop("checked", true)
                $(".txt-asistencia").val("ASISTIO");
            }
            else {
                $(".chk-asistencia").prop("checked", false)
                $(".txt-asistencia").val("FALTO");
            }
        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<table class="table">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>
            id_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            dni_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            nombre_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            ape_pat_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            ape_mat_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            asistencia_alumno
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            76475156
        </td>
        <td>
            GIAN FRANCO ALEXIS
        </td>
        <td>
            POMA
        </td>
        <td>
            VIDAL
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-asistencia">FALTO</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk-asistencia">
            <input type="text" class="txt-asistencia">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Charlas/Edit">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Details">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            2
        </td>
        <td>
            76475155
        </td>
        <td>
            GONZALO ALONSO
        </td>
        <td>
            GODOS
        </td>
        <td>
            VERA
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-asistencia">FALTO</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk-asistencia">
            <input type="text" class="txt-asistencia">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Charlas/Edit">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Details">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            3
        </td>
        <td>
            76475154
        </td>
        <td>
            DRUCILA
        </td>
        <td>
            VIDAL
        </td>
        <td>
            CALDERÓN
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-asistencia">ASISTIO</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk-asistencia">
            <input type="text" class="txt-asistencia">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Charlas/Edit">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Details">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas llamando a todos los elementos con las clases `'.chk-asistencia'` y `'.txt-asistencia'` asignando así el ultimo valor de la fila de la tabla para todos los campos, debes hacer
el cambio a los HERMANOS del label, para eso usar la funcion `parent()` para llegar al padre y luego `find()` para buscar en sus hijos ( osea los hermanos del label).

El código quedaria asi:

```js
function hanlderAsistencia(){
    $(".lbl-asistencia").each(function (index, element) {
        let estados = { 
               asistio: { text: "ASISTIO", check: true }, 
               falto: { text: "FALTO", check: false }
              };
       let estado = null;
       if (element.textContent == estados.asistio.text ) {
           estado = estados.asistio;
       }
       else {
           estado = estados.falto;  
       }
     elcheck = $(element).parent().find('.chk-asistencia');
     elinput = $(element).parent().find('.txt-asistencia');
     $(elcheck.get(0)).prop('checked',estado.check);
     $(elinput.get(0)).val(estado.text);
    });
}
hanlderAsistencia();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
            id_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            dni_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            nombre_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            ape_pat_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            ape_mat_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            asistencia_alumno
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            76475156
        </td>
        <td>
            GIAN FRANCO ALEXIS
        </td>
        <td>
            POMA
        </td>
        <td>
            VIDAL
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-asistencia">FALTO</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk-asistencia">
            <input type="text" class="txt-asistencia">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Charlas/Edit">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Details">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            2
        </td>
        <td>
            76475155
        </td>
        <td>
            GONZALO ALONSO
        </td>
        <td>
            GODOS
        </td>
        <td>
            VERA
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-asistencia">FALTO</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk-asistencia">
            <input type="text" class="txt-asistencia">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Charlas/Edit">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Details">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            3
        </td>
        <td>
            76475154
        </td>
        <td>
            DRUCILA
        </td>
        <td>
            VIDAL
        </td>
        <td>
            CALDERÓN
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-asistencia">ASISTIO</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk-asistencia">
            <input type="text" class="txt-asistencia">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Charlas/Edit">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Details">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, no sabia que a los parámetros de la función each() también se le puede colocar la sintaxis $("") de Jquery. :D